# Can anything be said about the cohomology class defined by a section of a vector bundle if it is not of the expected dimension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $E$ be a rank $n$ locally free sheaf on a smooth $n$ dimensional variety $X$, and $s\in H^0(X,E)$. If $\dim Z(s)=0$ (which is the expected dimension), then we can understand the cohomology class of $Z(s)$ as a chern class of $E$. Can anything be said about this class if $\dim Z(s)>0$?

Comment: I don't know what $Z(s)$ is but if it is the zero locus of $Z$, your identification with Chern class seems to be incorrect if the intersection with the zero section is not transversal due to lack of information of multiplicity.

Comment: @Z.M I meant for $Z(s)$ to denote the zero locus with its natural scheme structure, so including multiplicity information.

Comment: But in that case, how do you define the cohomology class of $Z(s)$ in that generality (i.e. for arbitrary subscheme)? Note that the usual intersection theory uses Chow's moving lemma to transform an arbitrary intersection into a proper intersection, in which case $\dim Z(s)=0$.

Comment: Let $z:Z(s)\to X$ be the inclusion of the zero-scheme. Assume that 
$Z(s)$ is smooth. Let $N$ be the normal bundle of $Z(s)$ in $X$. 
There is a natural monomorphism $N\to z^*(E)$, whose quotient 
$V$ (the so-called excess normal bundle) is locally free. 
We then have the formula
$$
c^{\rm top}(E)=z_*(c^{\rm top}(V)).
$$
This is a consequence of 
the "excess intersection formula" (see eg Fulton's book).
Eg, if $s$ is the zero-section, the formula is tautological and 
if $Z(s)$ is discrete then you recover the fact that $
c^{\rm top}(E)$ is the cycle class of the zero-scheme.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thanks, I did not know that! Should read up on my interestion theory I guess...

Comment: The class described by @DamianRössler exists even when $Z(s)$ is not smooth; it is called the localised Euler class of $E$ (where "localised" means to the zeros $Z(s)$ of $s$).
It is probably denoted $0_E^*[\Gamma_s]$ in Fulton's book, where $\Gamma_s$ is the graph of $s$ inside the total space of $E$ (and $0_E$ is the zero section).
It is a class on $Z(s)$ whose pushforward to $X$ is the top Chern class of $E$.

Answer (score 6):

Not much can be said. For instance, let $X = \mathbb{P}^n$ and $E = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus n}$. Then the zero locus of a section might be any linear subspace in $X$. In particular, its cohomology class is $H^k$, where $H$ is the hyperplane class and $k$ may be any integer in the range $0 \le k \le n$.